# iPython update interfers with Alt-Gr combinations

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just updated Python to 2.7.13 and Anaconda 4.4.0. Since the update, I cannot type the open square bracket ("[") into Jupyter. However, I can type the closed square bracket and copy paste the open square bracket without problem. I am using a French Canadian keyboard and to type these square brackets I do need to press a combination with "Alt-Gr". "Alt-Gr" seems to trigger something in Jupyter notebook and I'm guessing the exact combinations for open square bracket is used as a shortcut for something else. I cannot find it in the list of shortcuts as "Alt-Gr" doesn't seem to be a valid key when trying to edit keyboard shortcuts. Any clue of what's causing the issue?